# Storing similar unions in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, unions

I have one union defined like this:

```
typedef union opWord
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned short ARE : 2;
        unsigned short opDest : 2;
        unsigned short opSource : 2;
        unsigned short opcode : 4;
        unsigned short group : 2;
        unsigned short unused : 3;
    } word;
    unsigned short fullReg;
} opWord;
```

and another very similar one only differing by bitfield arrangement:

```
typedef union immediate
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned short ARE : 2;
        unsigned short imm : 13;
    } word;
    unsigned short fullReg;
} immediate;
```

Can these be stored in the same array somehow since they only vary by the arrangement of the bits?

Something like

```
opWord instructions[1000]?
```

If not, is there a way to do it as a linked list?
How would I declare pointers for that?

Comment: Create a union of the two unions?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot directly store objects of your types `opWord` and `immediate` in the same array.  You cannot declare such an array, and if you try to wrangle it with pointer casting and / or dynamically-allocated space then you run up against the strict aliasing rule.

What you *can* do is create a `union` type with an `opWord` and an `immediate` as members, and make an array of that type, as @jxh suggested in comments.  In its simplest, most concise form, that might look like this:

```
union {
    opWord op;
    immediate imm;
} instructions[1000];
```

You could also consider merging your two union types into one, and creating an array of that type:

```
union instruction {
    struct {
        unsigned short ARE : 2;
        unsigned short opDest : 2;
        unsigned short opSource : 2;
        unsigned short opcode : 4;
        unsigned short group : 2;
        unsigned short unused : 3;
    } opWord;
    struct {
        unsigned short ARE : 2;
        unsigned short imm : 13;
    } immediate;
    unsigned short fullReg;
};

union instruction instructions[1000];
```

That reduces the number of layers involved, which may be useful, at the cost of losing separate types for your two kinds of instructions.